# NSString with umlaute encoding

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring

i have created a plist with strings. Inside the strings i have umlaute, and can't encode them to be shown correctly. my code looks like this:

```
NSString *myFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"LevelText" ofType:@"plist"];

    strings = [[NSDictionary alloc]  initWithContentsOfFile:myFile ];
    stringkeys = [strings allKeys];
    NSEnumerator *enumerator = [strings objectEnumerator];

    while (value = [enumerator nextObject]) {
        if(![value isEqualToString:@""]){
            NSString *right = [NSString stringWithCString:value.UTF8String encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            NSLog(@"Value: %s", right.UTF8String);
        }

    }
```

i get load the plist into a NSDictionary object and then enumerate through it. I also looked at another example on stackoverflow but it doesn't work like that. The Umlaut always is represented like that:

> anh√∂ren

Comment: The Problem just occures inside the console, i printed out the String to my TextView and everything works fine. 
If i should delete the post maybe somebody should post a comment otherwise it could be a good help for somebody with the same problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get rid of all the extra calls to `UTF8String`. There's no reason to convert back and forth.

```
while (value = [enumerator nextObject]) {
    if([value length] > 0){ // A little safer approach that is a good habit to get into
        NSString *right = value;
        NSLog(@"Value: %@", right);
    }
}
```

If you still see trouble, then verify that `LevelText.plist` is UTF8 encoded, but I suspect the above will fix the problem.